# Unable to define boost::regex as private variable

Tags: c++

In the below code, i get error. What am i doing?

regex.cpp:11: error: expected identifier before string constant

regex.cpp:11: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class RH
{
public:
    bool  matches(const std::string & str);
private:
    boost::regex regex_("\\d:\\d-\\d:\\d"); // this is where error points to
};
```

Answer (score 4):

you must initialize in constructor:

```
class RH {
...
public:
    RH() : regex_("\\d:\\d-\\d:\\d") {}
...
private:
    boost::regex regex_;
}
```

Comment: but if i declare an array of class called Foo in private section of class such as Foo bar[22]; that works and i am assuming array is initilized and Foo() constructor is called 22 times, so why can i not construct regex()

Comment: regex() constructor is called, forwarded by RW()

Comment: When you say `Foo bar[22]`, then the compiler allocates 22 `Foo`s and calls the default parameterless `Foo` constructor 22 times. You can't do that if you want to pass some parameters in there. So you can construct a `boost::regex`` -- an empty one.

Comment: The error says expected identifier before string constant. Is there a way to make it pass by supplying some keyword?